# Why did Ant-Man appear in the Broadway musical?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, hawkeye-2021

The Hawkeye television series opens by showing a scene from the in-universe Broadway musical "Rogers" that is telling the story of the Battle of New York. In true Broadway form, each of the Avengers that were at the battle comes out and sings some sort of catchphrase and then goes back to dancing - there's Iron Man, Cap, Thor, Hulk, Widow, Hawkeye, Ant-Man... wait what??

Obviously, Ant-Man was not at the Battle of New York. I highly doubt that the Hawkeye showrunners forgot that, so putting him in the musical must have been a deliberate choice. It was funny, but was it added *purely* for comedic effect, or for some other deeper reason?

**Why did Ant-Man appear in the *Rogers* musical?**

Comment: Pretty sure it was actually Mephisto.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's not lupus

Comment: Downvote because Clint even calls this out himself.

Comment: To be fair, Ant-Man *was* there at the battle in upstate New York (in Endgame), so maybe they just had him in the opening number to establish all the characters, but when they got to the actual narrative part of the play, he'd be back in San Fran where he belongs until the last part.  (We don't know how much of the story is covered by that play...)

Comment: @ThePopMachine Sure, he calls out that Ant-Man wasn’t there. That’s not the question I asked. I asked *why* they added him to the musical, which I don’t think Clint addresses.

Comment: Clearly, the musical was written by a Variant who escaped the branch timeline where Ant-Man was running around in New York.

Comment: Actually, the early previews of _Rogers_ didn't feature Ant-Man, but a dedicated, passionate, grassroots campaign coalesced around the hashtag #releasethepymcut and achieved a stunning victory for fandom culture.

Comment: @SethMMorton:   Honestly, I think it's pretty obvious from Clint's comment that it's added so show how ridiculous and inaccurate the musical is.   And out-of-universe, that's the joke.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The writers of the brief bit of *Rogers: The Musical* we saw in *Hawkeye* shared the following with ScreenRant:

> "Scott and I were writing lyrics. I was like, 'We have to get things like Tesseract into the song, and Chitauri, and shawarma," said Shaiman. "[Marvel] knew the situation," added Wittman. "They wanted to musicalize the battle of New York. They did ask that Ant-Man be included in it because they wanted something where Clint would sit in the audience and go, 'Wait, he wasn't there. Why is he in this show?' That's just an example of, to both of us, of their humor, their sly humor.”
>
> “The main purpose of the song is for Clint to be kind of horrified at what he's seeing," continued Shaiman. "So we knew that we had to write, hopefully, a good, entertaining song, but it had to also be the kind of style of Broadway that would make someone who doesn't love Broadway musicals, not to mention someone who lived through what is being portrayed, just be kind of like, 'What this?' That was a perfect Marvel sense of humor, the fact that they wanted Ant-Man to be in it to show how usually people get these things wrong."
>
> <sup>[ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/hawkeye-show-rogers-musical-ant-man-included-why/)</sup>

So, basically, the writers of the show and the writers of the musical wanted there to be something that shouldn't be there, to make clear how bad the musical itself was (even *in-universe* and not just out of universe) and how much Broadway messes real events up with adaptations.

Comment: I think there was also a guy who was supposed to be Shang-Chi in there, another person who shouldn't have been there.  It's hard to tell because their costumes were so low-rent, but there was at least an Asian guy who didn't look like he was supposed to be any of the original Avengers, so not sure who else it could've been...

Comment: Maybe just ensemble singers? I don't know if Shang-Chi is publicly known at that point, and he *certainly* hasn't worked with the Avengers (yet).

Comment: The Asian dude who doesn't look like any of the original Avengers _is_ Ant-Man :)
https://twitter.com/AntManNews/status/1463651271072796678

Comment: Would the in-universe Broadway bunch be "The Ensemblers"?  

Comment: Seeing as the surname "Lang" is sometimes Chinese, I wonder if the idea is that the producers knew Ant-Man's name (Scott Lang), but not what he looked like, and made a bad assumption?

Comment: @gingerbreadboy Oh, yeah, that is the guy I was thinking about.  Doesn't really look anything like Ant-Man either, so I was a bit thrown, but then *none* of them look much like their "real" counterparts.  And yeah, I could see them screwing that up based on the name, especially since you can't really see his face when he's in the suit.

Comment: In fact there doesn't seem to have been a big ant-man sighting since "me eat people"...

Comment: I actually liked the musical. I'm only saying this because I know you guys can't downvote a comment.

Comment: @Blueriver But they can be flagged for moderator intervention /s

Comment: ♫ Oh, we're the heroes of the chorus / We hope you like our show / We know you're rootin' for us / But now we have to go ♫

Comment: As regards the Asian guy, it's also worth noting that a current trend, that might be even greater by 2024 in the MCU, is race/gender blind casting (except for casting non-minorities in minority roles). It actually raises some interesting questions on the rights of the writers and publishers on what they can do about it, but there was at least one production of Virgina Woolfe where it got shut down because the producers objected to the casting, saying that it substantially changed the meaning of the play (and they had grounds because part of the contract required approval for such changes).

Answer (score 14):

**This is normal and requires no explanation.**

I know, I know, Peter Nielsen's answer *has* an explanation, with a citation and everything, and I voted it up for that.  But even without Marvel's ‘sly humor’, this is exactly the kind of inaccuracy that you'd expect in a Broadway musical.  If the producers of *Rogers* expect their audience to know Ant-Man, and they have him in later scenes, then that's all the excuse they need to put him in this one.

To demonstrate this, let me look at a recent real-world historical Broadway musical, *Hamilton*.  Off the top of my head:

- Burr, Lafyette, and Laurens weren't in New York when Hamilton arrived and met Mulligan.  In fact, Hamilton didn't meet any of those three until after he joined the army.
- Burr was not at the duel between Laurens and Lee.  Lee's actual second was some guy you've probably never heard of.
- Neither Jefferson, nor Madison, nor Burr confronted Hamilton about the Reynolds affair.  The conversation between Hamilton and three Democratic-Republicans did happen, but the three were James Monroe and two others you've probably never heard of.
- There are so many inaccuracies in the election of 1800 that it would take up too much space to list them all here.  Suffice to say that it did not go down as shown.
- Also, the Presidential election of 1800 was not the cause of Burr's fatal challenge to Hamilton.  The actual cause was a gubernatorial election in 1804, not depicted in the musical, where Burr lost to somebody you've probably never heard of.

And there are many others that I could think of if I checked but are not coming to the top of my head.  I could also give examples from other historical musicals, such as *1776*, *Evita*, and *Six*.  But this is scifi, not history, so there's no need for a comprehensive list.  The point is that Broadway (and the West End) do this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While this seems to justify making fun of Broadway musicals, it doesn't really add anything to Peter's answer, which acknowledges this without really needing to dig into this level of detail.

Comment: @DavidW :  Yes, Peter's answer is good, but it risks understating how much Broadway does this.  It's not just something that Broadway *might* do that would horrify Clint; it's something that you'd *expect* Broadway to do (if not with Ant-Man then in some other way).  At first I was going to just make a comment on that answer, but then I thought that examples would help, so I wrote this.  I don't know to what extent you like having multiple answers with different perspectives on scifi.se, but I wrote this answer in hopes that it would be useful but never get voted up higher than Peter's. ☺️

Comment: Taking into account the liberties that *Hamilton* did with the truth, it’s almost like *Rogers* got too much right!

Answer (score -1):

This is an in-universe explanation consistent with what's seen,  but with no explicit support: **Ant-man was a consultant for the musical**

Consider:

1. What Avengers are available and willing to provide inside information about the Avengers?  Rogers, Romanoff, and Stark are dead, Clint clearly was not involved (and it doesn't seem likely that Bucky or the Falcon would be involved), and Thor is off-planet.  Banner might have been involved, but
2. The musical seems to reflect Ant-man's level of knowledge about the individual Avengers.  Ant-man admires Rogers' appearance - and the musical notes that Rogers and Thor are "easy on the eyes."  Ant-man doesn't know Romanoff very well, so all the musical notes is "she's a knockout who can knock you out" and likewise Clint Barton simply seems like a really nice guy.

Comment: 'Ant-man is one of the few living people who witnessed Rogers saying "I can do this all day"' — when did he witness this?

Comment: Darn.  I thought that Antman was observing the fight between the two Captains in "Endgame" - but while he went to the same time period, he wasn't with Capt.  I'm going to delete my answer after people have a chance to read this mea culpa.

Comment: Ah yeah I think Ant-Man heads downstairs to assist in stealing the Tesseract briefcase. I think the answer's still good, it's just the "I can do this all day" bit that might be wrong. Does Cap say it in the battle at the end of Endgame? If so I think Ant-Man might still be underground at that point, but I could be wrong. I _think_ Bucky heard him say it during the fight with Iron Man at the end of _Civil War_.